# Differences Between: 时候 vs. 的时候?

Tags: simplified-characters

Is there any rule when can I say 的时候 and when 时候?
For example: **小时候** and **小的时候**, is there any difference？

**求求大神们帮帮我**

Answer (score 1):

1. Most of the time the `的` should not be omitted. Exceptions include fixed expressions (e.g. `小時候`) or when pronouns are used (e.g. `什麼時候`, `這個時候`, `那時候`). In the latter case, adding `的` is not permitted.

   For other bisyllabic words, the `的` still should not be omitted: `下雨的時候` ('when it's raining').

   More so if we are using a *phrase*, as in

   > **飛機降落**的時候，請繫好安全帶。
   > Please fasten your seatbelts when *the plane is landing*.

   It's very unnatural to say `飛機降落時候`.
2. However, we don't require `的` if we use `～時` in `～的時候`'s stead:

   > 下雨時 
   > **飛機降落**時，請繫好安全帶。